# Hausdorff dimension of radial limit sets for divergence type subgroups

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $X$ be a proper $CAT(-1)$ space.
Let $\Gamma<Isom(X)$ be a subgroup of divergence type. 
Is it true that the Hausdorff dimension of the radial limit set of $\Gamma$ in $\partial X$ is equal to the Hausdorff dimension of the entire limit set?

Here, I mean Hausdorff dimension with respect to the metric on the boundary coming from the Gromov product.

Remark: I know the $\Gamma$ conformal (Patterson-Sullivan) measure gives full mass to the radial limit set, and also that the critical exponent is equal to the Hausdorff dimension of the radial limit set.
However this doesn't quite answer this question since in this generality the Patterson-Sullivan measure is not the Hausdorff measure.